# Como fazer a arma desaparecer na mesma tecla que faz ela aparecer no UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

   public class SelecteArma : MonoBehaviour {


    public bool Equipamento = true;

    void Start () {
    }


    void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("1")) {
    selecionarArma (0);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown ("2")) {
    selecionarArma (1);
    }
    }


    public void selecionarArma (int index){
    for (var i = 0; i<transform.childCount; i++) {
    if (i == index)
    transform.GetChild (i).gameObject.SetActiveRecursively (false);
    else
    transform.GetChild (i).gameObject.SetActiveRecursively (true);
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Podes simplesmente atribuir a uma variável bool a sua negação e usar isso para esconder e mostrar a arma.

```
var muda = true;

//atribui o valor contrário ao actual, se for true passa para false e vice-versa
muda = !muda;
```